# Shell Script: Hive query is not returning the value/result

Tags: shell, hive, sh, hiveql

I've the below code which I'm using to retrieve the hive result, storing it in a variable, doing the comparison and then accordingly printing the message using shell script.

```
        count_students=`/usr/bin/hive -e 'select count(*) from student_records.fresher;'`
        echo $count_students
        if [ $count_students -gt 0 ]; then
            echo "There are students to be grouped." 
            exit 1
        else
            echo "There are no students to be grouped." 
        fi
        echo "Student count to check for Freshers is completed."
```

But the code is not returning anything i.e.:

Actual O/P:

```
-bash: line 2: [: -ge: unary operator expected
There are no students to be grouped.
```

Also the `echo $count_students` is not printing anything.

The hive query gives the result as:

```
admin$ select count(*) from student_records.fresher;
179
```

Not getting why the hive is not able to return the result. Bcz of that the query is prompting wrong message. Any help/ suggestion will be really helpful. Thanks to the community.

Comment: Try using $() in place of `(back-quotes) for hive query substitution, backquotes are an old style command substitution format and could be causing issue due to usage of nested quotes.

Comment: `count_students=$(/usr/bin/hive -e "select count(*) from student_records.fresher;")`

Comment: Please refer the below link. see if this helps
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable